# Getting the handler inside on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#handler').on('click', '.selector', function(){
    alert( $(this).text());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="handler">
  handler content
  <a href="#" class="selector">selector content</a>
</div>
```

How do I get the `#handler` inside the `on` method without explicitly specifying it?

Comment: @JaromandaX without specifying explicitly ofcourse.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I want both.

Comment: @3zzy Why not explicitly? You'd have more code to write if not explicitly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the event "delegateTarget" property

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#handler').on('click', '.selector', function(e){
        console.log(e.delegateTarget);
    });
});
```

Working example:-

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#handler').on('click', '.selector', function(e){
      console.log(e.delegateTarget);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="handler">
  handler content
  <a href="#" class="selector">child</a>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="selector">grand child</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="selector">great grand child</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this one much better.+1.I have added working example part. Hope it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for making it a working snippet @AlivetoDie - (was going to, but got distracted) :p

Comment: you'r welcome. but will it work in nested children cases?(Means getting always the first parent no matter how many nested elements inside parent and no matter where it clicked inside parent element?)

Comment: I've just added nested children and it all works well - it doesn't get the parent, it get's the `#handler` every time (as I think is the requirement)

Comment: good that you edited that in your answer. now it's the perfect answer among all.

Comment: There's always an elegant way, glad to have found it. I don't understand the downvotes really on the question, its a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you can directly use the unique id you have

```
$("#handler").
```

In case if that is a class, you have `$(this).parent()` to the top level.

you can chain it to nth level , till you reach the top. `$(this).parent().parent()`...

or since you know the selector, you can do `$(this).parents("selector")`

Comment: In this small example its a direct parent.

Comment: Or use `.parents('SOME_SELECTOR')`

Comment: @Mr.Alien [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) will return all the matched elements. Imagine the case when used a class in it like `parents('.class')` so better to use `closest()`.

Comment: @RohanKumar Oh yes, `.closest()` makes more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) if the parent has hierarchy,

```
$(this).closest('div')
```

and use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent) if it is direct parent of target element,

```
$(this).parent('div');
```

And the selector is unique and has id like `handler` then the best option is

```
$('#handler')
```

Answer (score -1):

Change it to

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#handler').on('click', function(){
    //$(this) here will be #handler.
  });  
});
```

Or if you still want the function to fire when someone clicks on `.selector` then you can do the following

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#handler').on('click', '.selector', function(){
    var handler = $(this).parent();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: 2 nd one is right. First one is not needed to OP.he specifically ask that after click on child how to get parent selector.remove 1st one from your answer.Ican do that but i don't want to.for 2nd one +1